# iOS - display google results in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios

I have question about displaying google results in UIWebView - using normal request e.g. http://www.google.pl/search?q=ios  . I want use it in commercial application, are there any google licensing restrictions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you're not modifying the webpage returned by a standard web search (like http://www.google.pl/search?q=ios), you are fine.

> Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide. You may use our Services only as permitted by law, including applicable export and re-export control laws and regulations. We may suspend or stop providing our Services to you if you do not comply with our terms or policies or if we are investigating suspected misconduct.

Source: [Google Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Types of search engine query**

1. Google Search   = http://google.com/search?q=ios
2. Yahoo Search    = http://search.yahoo.com/?q=ios
3. Bing Search     = http://www.bing.com/search?q=ios
4. Ask Search      = http://www.ask.com/web?q=ios